# Mat Expansion Panel show indicator on disabled and change direction of animation

Tags: css, angular, animation, angular-material

I am trying to edit the CSS of the matexpansion indicator. I want the arrow animation to turn inward instead of outward and I want the indicator to still show when it is disabled I tried adding this attribute `hideToggle='false'` but when disabled it overides it and hides the indicator. To change the direction of the animation I read on the docs about using: `const EXPANSION_PANEL_ANIMATION_TIMING: "225ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0.0,0.2,1)";` but I am not sure wher to place it in my code, Here is my stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2sodq?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts

```
<mat-expansion-panel  hideToggle = "false" disabled = true>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Personal data
      </mat-panel-title>
```

Comment: Check this change I made based on your [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2sodq-7rtcev?file=styles.css) Is this correct what I am understanding?

Comment: Yes! didn't realize  it was that simple at least for the rotation part Thanks. Any thoughts for displaying the indicator even while its disabled

Comment: If you think as per UX, if an `expansion-panel` is disabled, it is better not to show the `indicator`' as it leads to bad UX.

Comment: Yeah I agree but not my decision

Comment: Ok then let me check how to get a workaround for that.

Comment: Please check my answer. It is as per your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the `chevron` or `indicator` even when the panel is disabled try as below:

**HTML**

```
<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="boolCondition">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      Personal data
      // you have to add the below span tag in every expansion panel with a condition
      <span *ngIf="boolCondition"  class="mat-expansion-indicator"></span>
    </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

**CSS**

```
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
   transform: rotate(225deg) !important;
}

// for the mat-expansion indicator to displayed when it is disabled
.mat-expansion-indicator {
   position: absolute;
   right: 55px;
}
```

[stackblitz working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2sodq-7rtcev?file=styles.css)

Comment: Remove this `.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
   transform: rotate(225deg) !important;
}` from CSS. Maybe you have to settle with default behavior.

Comment: So there's no other way?

Comment: From my understanding you want the indicator to open exact opposite to the current default behaviour, right ?

Comment: Well oringinally the mat expansion is on the right and opens inward toward the content(left) but I moved the indicator to the left side next to the title That's why I wanted it to open towards the left and it's working fine. But now when the panel is open the indicator is pointing down instead of up

Comment: Did you remove the CSS `.mat-expansion-indicator::after { transform: rotate(225deg) !important; }` as this is making the indicator act differently

Comment: Is there a way to show hide the indicator strictly in the your css file like say `mat-indicator:disabled`